# Angular Unit Test, SpyOn stand-alone function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to test an Angular app and would like to test that the getItem() function within my controller is called when the ready() function of the controller is called.

**--- Controller ---**

```
var vm = this;
vm.items = [];
$ionicPlatform.ready(ready);

function ready() {
     vm.items.push(getItem());

     function getItem(){
          var item = //do stuff to get item;
          console.log('getItem called');
          return item;
     }
}
```

**--- Spec ---**

```
describe('Controller', function(){

     //--- Load app with dependencies and module to test code omitted.

     beforeEach(function(){
          //How do I spy on getItem() to test that it was called?
          //I've tried getItem = jasmine.createSpy()
          //I've tried spyOn(window, 'getItem')
     }

     //--- Initialize the controller and a mock scope code omitted.

     beforeEach(function(done){
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
               done();
          });
     });

     it('getItem function should get called', function(){
          expect(getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();

          //--- Note, getItem does not get called according to the expect statement, 
          //--- but does output 'getItem called' to the terminal when running the test.
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you've come upon a fundamental limit of Javascript unit testing with Jasmine-- you can only `spyOn` methods that are exposed on some object.  If there is a function that is internal to another function, and not exposed in anyway, you cannot test it directly.

However, you do have two options available to you:

1. Expose the function in a way that it can be spied on (generally as a method of whatever Angular component you are testing).
2. Test it indirectly.

The first is probably relatively self-evident, but the latter may be a little confusing.  Basically, you can't test *directly* if the `getItems` function is called, but the function may have downstream methods it calls or values it changes you can test.  For instance, you can test that `vm.items.push` is larger after `ready` is called, or you can `spyOn(console.log)` and `expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('getItem called')`.

You can find arguments for both approaches on the internet-- I tend to prefer approach two because I don't like doing refactors *solely* for the purpose of testability, but many will argue that refactoring for testability generally yields better code.  That choice is yours to make.  Hope this helps!